# Reverse and square

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic, sequence, number-theory, base-conversion

In this challenge you will compute numbers from a curious sequence.

Your input is a single decimal nonnegative integer. Reverse the bits in this integer and then square the number to get the required output.

When reversing the bits you must not use any leading zeroes in the input. For example:

```
26 (base 10) = 11010 (base 2) -> 01011 (base 2) = 11 -> 11*11 = 121
```

The first 25 inputs/outputs of this sequence:

```
0: 0
1: 1
2: 1
3: 9
4: 1
5: 25
6: 9
7: 49
8: 1
9: 81
10: 25
11: 169
12: 9
13: 121
14: 49
15: 225
16: 1
17: 289
18: 81
19: 625
20: 25
21: 441
22: 169
23: 841
24: 9
```

Your solution should work for arbitrarily sized integers. If your language does not have a convenient built-in method of using those, implement your answer as if it does. You are then excused if your answer breaks for large numbers. However, do not use tricks/bounds that only work for a limited domain (such as a lookup table).

---

Your score is the number of bytes of source code.

**-50% bonus if you never convert the number to/from binary.** This is not limited to builtins, if you loop over the number bit by bit (either by shifting or masking or any other method), it will also count as conversion. *I don't know whether this is actually possible, but it gives an incentive to spot a pattern in the sequence.*

Smallest score wins.

Comment: [So close](https://oeis.org/A191871)

Comment: If the code calls a method that results in a character string that represents the bits, is that eligible for the bonus?

Comment: @BradGilbertb2gills No.

Comment: I presume that using math to extract the bits also counts as binary conversion?

Comment: @ThomasKwa Yes.

Comment: If the code converts to a hex string, then uses magic to reverse bits in each nybble, then reverses all nybbles in the hex string, does that qualify for the bonus?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma No. Only a radically different approach (such as a closed algebraic form) qualifies for the bonus. As I've said in the question - I'm not certain whether that's possible at all.

Comment: Can I use binary conversion if I'm converting a separate result? (For the bonus)

Comment: [Relevant](https://oeis.org/A030101) and [relevant](https://projecteuler.net/problem=463)

Comment: This challenge is conversion-to-bits away from a Dock Length 5 [Fishing](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fishing) solution: `IrnSP`.

Comment: I take it partitioning a number into powers of 2 (e.g. using Mathematica's `IntegerPartition`) also counts as conversion to binary?

Comment: @MartinBüttner Yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Par](http://ypnypn.github.io/Par/), 5 bytes

```
✶Σ⌐Σ²
```

That's read-binary-reverse-binary-square.

Comment: [I count 12](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#%E2%9C%B6%CE%A3%E2%8C%90%CE%A3%C2%B2)

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ That byte counter assumes UTF-8. I believe Mauris is using some encoding that is not UTF-8 to count his bytes, but he did not specify this encoding.

Comment: Par uses its own weird encoding. Its canonical representation is a certain subset of <256 Unicode characters. I'm not sure if it has a name; I should wait for @Ypnypn to chime in.

Comment: Oh, I see. @orlp

Comment: Possibly it has its own SBCS?

Answer (score 21):

### Mathematica, <s>42</s> 21 bytes

*Thanks to alephalpha for halving the score.*

```
#~IntegerReverse~2^2&
```

The actual reason I did this in Mathematica was because I wanted to look at a plot... it sure looks funny:

[image]

Comment: But I like the score! XD

Comment: why does this answer have more votes than the answer with the least bytes? o_O

Comment: @Seadrus You know what they say. A picture is worth 7 bytes.

Comment: Nice plot. The distribution does not look too surprising to me. You would expect the range of results to quadruple every time the input reaches a new power of 2 (i.e. has an additional bit). Then, within that range, the values are sort of randomly distributed, with a bias to lower values since  the result is the square of a uniformly distributed value.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Actually, since trailing zeroes of the input are ignored, it's not quite uniform and even more biased to lower values :P

Comment: so your score is 42 + 7 = 49 bytes :P

Comment: @Sp3000 I think that's part of the uniformity. For each binary length, we get every odd number up to that length exactly once.

Comment: `#~IntegerReverse~2^2&`

Comment: @alephalpha ah nice, I forgot that takes a base.

Comment: Sorry, @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Oh well. 21 is okay in its own right ;)

Comment: Good money says it shelves again after 1024. I wonder how the distribution compares to true uniform distribution after culling some of the condensed clusters at the bottom. Does the shelving hold up in base 3? base 10? I'd be interested to see it.

Comment: @Seadrus Because it's insightful and interesting!

Comment: @corsiKa 12 votes more insightful?

Comment: Mathematica is not specifically designed for golfing like the languages that usually win these kinds of competitions, which makes this answer more impressive than those in some ways.

Comment: @Seadrus jokes aside, the shortest solution is no more interesting or impressive than any other solution, because they all us the same approach and it's only shortest due to having short built-ins for parts of the solution. In that sense, the plot does give this answer the edge.

Comment: right. but in another sense, this is a code-golf question

Answer (score 8):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/Japt), <s>29</s> <s>28</s> <s>11</s> 7 [bytes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859)

<sup>(You can save the program as a 7-byte IEC_8859-1-encoded file, then upload it to the [interpreter](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt).)</sup>

Japt is shortened JavaScript made by [ETHproductions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42545/ethproductions).

```
¢w n2 ²
```

[Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=oncgbjIgsg==&input=MjM=)

Explanation:

1. `¢` is shortcut to `Us2`, which compiles to `U.s(2)`. `U` is input (implicit), `.s(2)` called by a number, invokes `.toString(2)` (converts to binary, parses as string).
2. `w` compiles to `.w()`, which reverses the string (`.split('').reverse().join('')`).
3. `n2` works as `parseInt(<number>,2)`, i.e. converts binary to decimal.
4. `²` invokes `Math.pow(<number>,2)`, i.e. squares the number.

Comment: There's a string function toNumber on `n`, so you could do `Us2 a w a n2 p2`. Good job though!

Comment: Also, `w` works the same on strings as it does on arrays, so you don't need the two `a`s :)

Comment: One last thing: `Us2 ` = `¢`, and `p2` = `²`, bringing it down to 7 bytes: `¢w n2 ²`

Comment: I get 9 bytes [here](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#%C2%A2w%20n2%20%C2%B2).  Surely `¢` and `²` are 2 bytes each according to [this utf8 table](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/).  Or are you using some other weird encoding or codepage?

Comment: @Dig it's seven bytes per this encoding  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859.  I've linked the interpreter I used - http://bytesizematters.com/.

Comment: @nicael I've used that interpreter before and was [called out on it](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/63057/revisions).

Comment: @Cᴏɴᴏʀ Ok, as it's considered invalid to use anything other than UTF-8, I've stated it's 9 bytes, so as not to be considered a cheater.

Comment: @nicael If my understanding of IEC_8859 encoding is correct (I may be wrong), I think your program encoded accordingly is the output of `echo -n a277206e3220b2 | xxd -p -r`.  If I paste this into the online interpreter I get "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL".  The UTF8 encoding can be generated with `echo -n c2a277206e3220c2b20a | xxd -p -r` and works fine.  If you have an interpreter that understands the IEC_8859 encoding, then I'm fine with you claiming 7 bytes.

Comment: The [online interpreter](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=master&code=oncgbjIgsg==&input=ImFiYyIgMTMgWzkgInp5eCJd) now accepts IEC_8859-1 encoded files. (Although I'm not sure how to do UTF-8 and UTF-16 as well...)

Comment: @ETHproductions - now I can +1 this :)

Comment: @ETHproductions The online interpreter breaks in IE on tablet.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ I'd arranged the site so that it looked good on my screen, but maybe not many others. This should be fixed now. Is that what you meant by "breaks"?

Comment: @ETHproductions It's beautiful :D

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Great, glad you like it :) BTW, nicael, I've added a section on Unicode shortcuts.

Answer (score 7):

### [Minkolang 0.14](https://github.com/elendiastarman/Minkolang), 43 bytes

Thanks to Mego for inspiring this.

```
n1{d1`,2$3*&$z2zd2%-2l$Md1%-;z2%*z2:{+}2;N.
```

[Test the code here](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/minkolang/?code=n1%7Bd1%60%2C2%243*%26%24z2zd2%25-2l%24Md1%25-%3Bz2%25*z2%3A%7B%2B%7D2%3BN%2E&input=22) and [check all test cases here](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/minkolang/?code=%28ndN1%7Bd1%60%2C2%243*%26%24z2zd2%25-2l%24Md1%25-%3Bz2%25*z2%3A%7B%2B%7DnN2%3BNlO%24I%29%2E&input=0%3A%200%0A1%3A%201%0A2%3A%201%0A3%3A%209%0A4%3A%201%0A5%3A%2025%0A6%3A%209%0A7%3A%2049%0A8%3A%201%0A9%3A%2081%0A10%3A%2025%0A11%3A%20169%0A12%3A%209%0A13%3A%20121%0A14%3A%2049%0A15%3A%20225%0A16%3A%201%0A17%3A%20289%0A18%3A%2081%0A19%3A%20625%0A20%3A%2025%0A21%3A%20441%0A22%3A%20169%0A23%3A%20841%0A24%3A%209).

#### Explanation

This uses this recurrence relation:

```
a(0) = 0
a(1) = 1
a(2n) = a(n)
a(2n+1) = a(n) + 2^(floor(log_2(n))+1)
```

If `n` is the input, then `a(n)` is the resulting number after its binary sequence has been flipped. 0 and 1 are obvious. For `a(2n) = a(n)`, consider that `x0` (where `x` is any sequence of binary digits) flipped is `0x`, which is the same as `x`. For `a(2n+1)`, the reasoning is a bit more complicated. `x1` flipped is `1x`, which is equal to `x + 2^k` for some `k`. This `k` is one more than the number of digits in `x`, which is `floor(log_2(n))+1`. The full formula follows, except that it's modified a bit. This is what I actually code:

```
a(0) = 0
a(1) = 1
a(n) = a(n//2) + (n%2) * 2^(floor(log_2(n - n%2)))
```

As Mego and I worked out in chat, `floor(n/2) = (n - n%2)/2`. Thus, `log_2(floor(n/2))+1 = log_2(n - n%2)`. Furthermore, multiplying by `(n%2)` collapses both the odd and even parts into one expression.

Finally, without any further ado, here's the code, explained.

```
n                                              Take number from input
 1{                                            Start recursion that takes only one element
   d1`,                                        1 if top of stack 0 or 1, 0 otherwise
       2$3*                                    26
           &                                   Jump if top of stack is not zero
            $z                                 Store top of stack in register (z)
               
               zd2%-                           n - n%2
                    2l$M                       log_2(n - n%2)
                        d1%-                   floor(log_2(n - n%2))
              2             ;                  2^floor(log_2(n - n%2))
                             z2%               n%2
                                *              Multiply
                                 z2:           n//2
                                    {          Recurse
                                     +         Add
                                      }        Return
                                       2;N.    Square it, output as number, and stop.
```

Comment: I think the recurrence is just a reformulation of iterating over the individual bits.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't count. Whenever you see `2n` and `2n+1` in a recurrence relation you should immediately think of it as looping over bits.

Comment: @orlp: Well, that's a bummer. I'm kinda convinced now that your bonus is impossible.

Comment: @El'endiaStarman I've almost got it, I think.

Answer (score 6):

## Python, 32 bytes

```
lambda x:int(bin(x)[:1:-1],2)**2
```

[Try it online.](http://ideone.com/r1Sx4H)

The code is pretty straightforward: `bin(6)`, for example, gives `0b110`, the binary representation of 6. `[:1:-1]` reverses the string and removes `0b`. `int` converts the string to an integer from binary, and `**2` squares it.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jolf](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Jolf/), 7 bytes

[Just run it.](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=UUNfQmoy) The input on the page doesn't work.

```
^C_Bj22
```

### Explanation

```
^C_Bj22
    j   numeric input
   B    convert to binary (str)
  _     reverse
 C   2  parse as binary integer to base 10
^     2 square
        implicit output
```

---

I added the `Q` command, which makes this 6 bytes: `QC_Bj2`

Comment: Crossed out 7 still looks like a 7.

Comment: @quartata Not as bad as a crossed out 4.

Answer (score 4):

## [TeaScript](https://github.com/vihanb/TeaScript), 9 [bytes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859) <s>11</s>

TeaScript is Javascript for golfing

```
®x÷v¤)**2
```

Will golf more once I get back to my computer

[Try it online!](http://vihanserver.tk/p/TeaScript/#?code=%22$p(%C2%AEx%C3%B7v%C2%A4)%C2%A4)%22&inputs=%5B%2211%22%5D&opts=%7B%22int%22:true,%22ar%22:false,%22debug%22:false,%22chars%22:false,%22html%22:false%7D)

[Test all](http://vihanserver.tk/p/TeaScript/#?code=%22r(25)m(%23%20%20$p(%C2%AEl%C3%B7v%C2%A4)%C2%A4)%20%20);%22&inputs=%5B%2211%22%5D&opts=%7B%22int%22:true,%22ar%22:false,%22debug%22:false,%22chars%22:false,%22html%22:false%7D)

Comment: Does the interpreter understand any encodings other than UTF8?  Using UTF8 encoding, I think [your entry is 12 bytes long](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#%C2%AEx%C3%B7v%C2%A4%29%2a%2a2).

Answer (score 4):

## J, <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
2^~|.&.#:
```

This is a tacit, monadic verb. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/j#@5@mYGulYBRXV6Onpqds9T81OSNfIU3JQCFTT8HI9D8A)

*Thanks to @randomra for golfing off 1 byte!*

#### How it works

```
2^~|.&.#:  Right argument: y

       #:  Convert y to binary.
   |.      Reverse the digits.
     &.    Dual; apply the inverse of #:, i.e., convert back to integer.
 ^~        Apply power (^) with reversed argument order (~)...
2          to 2 and the previous result.
```

Comment: Link doesn't work, I get a 404 error on a google page that says "The requested URL /host/0B3cbLoy-_9Dbb0NaSk9MRGE5UEU/index.html was not found on this server. That’s all we know."

Answer (score 4):

### [Seriously](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
2;,¡R¿ª
```

Challenges like these are perfect for Seriously :)

[Try it online](http://seriouslylang.herokuapp.com/link/code=323b2cad52a8a6&input=26)

Explanation:

```
2;,¡    get a string representing the (decimal) input in binary, with a 2 on the bottom of the stack
R      reverse the string
¿    convert binary string to decimal int (using that extra 2 from earlier)
ª      square it
```

Comment: Nice job matching Jolf!

Comment: +1 for having your interpreter accept CP437 encoding (or at least the hex representation of it)

Answer (score 3):

### [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 21 bytes

```perl6
{:2(.base(2).flip)²}
```

Example usage:

```perl6
say {:2(.base(2).flip)²}(26); # 121

say (0..24).map: {:2(.base(2).flip)²};
# (0 1 1 9 1 25 9 49 1 81 25 169 9 121 49 225 1 289 81 625 25 441 169 841 9)

my &code = {:2(.base(2).flip)²};
say code 3; # 9

say chars code 10¹⁰⁰; # 140
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, <s>64</s> <s>63</s> <s>56</s> 53 bytes

```
n=>parseInt([...n.toString(2)].reverse().join``,2)**2
```

I realize I'm extra long, but hey, I can do it :P

[Demo](http://www.es6fiddle.net/ihkxrore)

Comment: instead of `parseInt(` you can do `+("0b"+`

Comment: @Downgoat hm, it doesn't appear to give correct results.

Comment: `[...n.toString(2)]` and `.join\`\``

Comment: Even shorter w/ ES7 (49 bytes): `n=>+("0b"+[...n.toString(2)].reverse().join\`\`)**2`. Doesn't work in any browsers yet

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Thanks, this saves some bytes.

Comment: This works for me in the latest version of Firefox: `n=>(y=+('0b'+[...n.toString(2)].reverse().join``))*y` (51 bytes) Or with exponentiation, 49 bytes:`n=>+('0b'+[...n.toString(2)].reverse().join``)**2` but this doesn't work yet.

Comment: @Eth In Safari it doesn't work, gonna try in Chrome.

Comment: @Eth With Chrome, the first example (51 bytes) *doesn't* work, but the second does. Those don't seem to be universal anyway.

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 10 bytes

```
ri2bW%2b_*
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=ri2bW%252b_*&input=17)

Answer (score 2):

## Shell, 25

```bash
dc -e2o?p|rev|dc -e2i?d*p
```

Input/output via STDIN/STDOUT:

```bash
$ echo 26|dc -e2o?p|rev|dc -e2i?d*p
121
$
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 45 bytes

```
echo pow(bindec(strrev(decbin($argv[1]))),2);
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 35 bytes

```
->(x){x.to_s(2).reverse.to_i(2)**2}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
bRCn
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/Kcg57/9/IzMA)

## Explanation

```
     Implicit input
b    Convert to binary
 R   Reverse
  C  Convert from binary
   n Square
     Implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
àxå²
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##DcurEYAwFEVBf6rJffmXgwEEDAZBORgaoARSWIjdmd2nc12Obe693Vd7vrd3hzA8gUgiU6hooJAhjwKKKKGMCqqYw8YxzGPhBw)

**Explanation:**

```python
à     # Convert the (implicit) input-integer to a binary-string
 x    # Reverse this string
  å   # Convert it from a binary-string back to an integer
   ²  # Take the square of this integer
      # (after which the entire stack joined together is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
bṘB²
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJi4bmYQsKyIiwiIiwiMTEiXQ==)

```
bṘB²
bṘB  # Convert to binary, reverse, convert back to decimal
   ² # Square
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 40 bytes

```
#+##&~Fold~Reverse@IntegerDigits[#,2]^2&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcq9CsIwFIbhW/kgkMUj9sS/OigdRHAT1xAhaFoDtkIaXMTeejzDO71P7/Mz9D7Huy8t9kXNlNLT6f16TNfwCWkMzXnIoQvpGLuYR6vIuJvR5ZLikK3C/IDWKuegsWjwZYIhLAkrwpqwIWwJNWFH4EqSzwJYBAthMSyIRbEwFmeqX/kD)

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com), <s>124</s> 72 bytes

```
f(n)=total(mod(floor(n/2^l),2)2^k/2^l)^2
k=floor(log_2(n+0^n))
l=[k...0]
```

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/veegjtgbcr)

*-52 bytes thanks to Aiden Chow*

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), 38 bytes

```
(#0)
0#s=s^2
n#s=div n 2#(2*s+n`mod`2)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ0W0km5yQYFS7OI025ilpSVpuhY31TSUDTS5DJSLbYvjjLjygHRKZplCnoKRsoaRVrF2XkJufkqCkSZE9Y7cxMw8BVuFlHwuBYWCosy8EgUVhTQFIzOI9IIFEBoA)

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth - 9 bytes

Straightforward conversions. I actually assigned 2 to a var which is pretty weird.

```
^i_jQK2KK
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%5Ei_jQK2KK&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9%0A10%0A11%0A12%0A13%0A14%0A15%0A16%0A17%0A18%0A19%0A20%0A21%0A22%0A23%0A24%0A25%0A26&debug=0).

Answer (score 1):

## , 12 chars / 21 bytes

```
⦅`ᶀ`+ᴙ(ïß2)²
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter.html?eval=true&input=5&code=%E2%A6%85%60%E1%B6%80%60%2B%E1%B4%99%28%C3%AF%C3%9F2%29%C2%B2)</kbd>

### Noncompetitive answer, 9 chars / 18 bytes

```
⦅Յ+ᴙ(ïⓑ)²
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter.html?eval=true&input=5&code=%E2%A6%85%D5%85%2B%E1%B4%99%28%C3%AF%E2%93%91%29%C2%B2)</kbd>

Comment: Via [this](http://bytesizematters.com) byte counter, gives 15 bytes (uses another encoding).

Comment: I grade using UTF-8 (until I can get Mines encoding to work).

Comment: The... name of the language... is boxes?

Comment: It's ESMin in doublestruck. The Unicode chars aren't fully supported.

Answer (score 1):

### Pyth, 9 bytes

```
^i_.BQ2 2
```

This is a very simple pyth based answer similar to the Python one

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic (TI-84 Plus CE), 42 bytes

```
Prompt X
0→S
While X
2S→S
If X/2≠int(X/2
S+1→S
End
S2
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 38 bytes

```c
r;f(n){for(r=n%2;n/=2;r+=r+n%2);r*=r;}
```

Reverse all the bits, square the result. Pretty standard.

*-1 byte thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYvBCgIxDETv/YqwUEjsilLwYuyf7GVpqeRgVoJ4Wfbba@tcHsObyednzq0ZV1Ta62ZoSX1kvaTIFpKF3ojtlIyPJvqB1yqK300Kud1BzzgNIZDgyh0PiLfOEOjvR97WFxUnX@7gy6LTDDJDRSFid7Qf)

Comment: [37 bytes](https://tio.run/##HYsxCsMwDEV3n0IEDFad0mDoUlU36VJsXDRUKaJkCTm7a/ctb3j/5/Mr59aMalDc62rBeCElvXBCi2xRfSI7sdHRRL/wfoqGbZWCbnfQGZ8RBBgW6rpDunbHiP8@@Fhf1DD5cgNfHjrNIDPUIIjkjvYD)

Answer (score 1):

## Splunk (v8.2.6) Search Processing Language, <strike>182</strike> 170 bytes:

```
|inputcsv b|foreach *[eval x=<<FIELD>>]|eval p=mvrange(0,floor(log(x,2)+1))|mvexpand p|eval x=floor(x/pow(2,p))%2|stats list(x) as x|eval x=tonumber(mvjoin(x,""),2),x=x*x
```

<strike>Big data. Smallish code.</strike>

Am learning Splunk for work, and decided to try to have a bit of fun with it.

Input is expected in a file at $SPLUNK_HOME/var/run/splunk/csv/b.csv. The file must contain the number in base 10 followed by a newline. The output is the search result, which is analogous to an SQL `SELECT`. This is as close to our standard I/O rules as I could reasonably do in SPL, but I'm willing to work something out if this is problematic.

With whitespace:

```
| inputcsv b
| foreach * [eval x=<<FIELD>>] 
| eval p=mvrange(0,floor(log(x,2)+1))
| mvexpand p
| eval x=floor(x/pow(2,p))%2
| stats list(x) as x
| eval x=tonumber(mvjoin(x,""),2),x=x*x
```

Explanation (I plan to flesh this out more later):

````
| inputcsv b                            ``` Read in b ```
| foreach * [eval x=<<FIELD>>]          ``` Get the value into a field "x" (Splunk reads our "CSV" file in as an event with one field, named the value we want, with a value of the empty string.) ``` 
| eval p=mvrange(0,floor(log(x,2))+1)   ``` Create a multivalue field "p" which contains the numbers 0 to the number of bits required to represent our number, the order here also means we get the reverse for free ```
| mvexpand p                            ``` Expand our single event with a multivalue field "p" into multiple events, each with a certain value of p ```
| eval x=floor(x/pow(2,p))%2            ``` Calculate (x/(2**p))%2, and set that value back to x```
| stats list(x) as x                    ``` Collect the values of x back into a single multivalue event ```
| eval x=tonumber(mvjoin(x,""),2),x=x*x ``` Combine all the bits back into a string, and convert that string back into a numeric value, then square it```
```result is a single event with field x, containing the square of the bit reversed input.```
````

Edit: forgot how math works (ceil instead of floor + 1 for the bit length calculation), and managed to only check with inputs that worked with my wrong math. Also sort happened to be a leftover from when I was doing the problem more verbosely, we get the reverse sort for free. Nets to -12.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 38 bytes

```perl
$_=(oct"0b".reverse sprintf"%b",$_)**2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lYjP7lEySBJSa8otSy1qDhVobigKDOvJE1JNUlJRyVeU0vL6P9/I5N/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DAwN/usWAAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [LOLCODE](http://lolcode.org/), 192 bytes

```
HAI 1.3
I HAS A s ITZ 0
I HAS A x
GIMMEH x
IM IN YR l
s R SUM OF PRODUKT OF s 2 MOD OF x 2
x R QUOSHUNT OF x 2
BOTH SAEM x 0,O RLY?
YA RLY
GTFO
OIC
IM OUTTA YR l
VISIBLE PRODUKT OF s s
KTHXBYE
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3LCsIwFET3@Yr5AJFawa2k9pFLm17NQ4xbdVfoIpv@fWwQBVdzZhg40zw95ucrJSUJu@1eEJS0kIggd0fx64voSOtGrUAaNCIYTCLCwHoNbnE2XPveZYwoobnOuKAUy3q6eLbKj@67VewUrGz02ooNwwzhKILMKTrXsmA6ZRF75@THdSVL1dD8i6LonbpVoUmpPLwB)

Answer (score 0):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents), 10 bytes

```
K\rJ$)))^2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/3zumyEtFU1Mzzuj/fyMzAA)

First time using cQuents.

### Explanation

```
    $      # Take the index.
   J )     # Convert to (default) base 2.
 \r   )    # Reverse it.
K      )   # Convert from (default) base 2 to base 10.
        ^2 # And square it.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 24 bytes

```
[ >bin reverse bin> sq ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqVQnFpYmpqXnFqskJtYkqFXkFhUnFoEZitkpxblpeYoFBSllpRUFhRl5pUoWHNxGVr@j1awS8rMUyhKLUsFqlYAsu0UigsVYv8nJ@bkKOj9BwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), 4 bytes

```
BUḄ²
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700KzUnp3LBgqWlJWm6FsudQh_uaDm0aUlxUnIxVGxJtJFZLJQNAA)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 39 bytes

```javascript
n=>`0b${(g=n=>n?n%2+g(n>>1):'')(n)}`**2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7RboIwFIbv@xTnwqWtQ0K7ilADXu0p5hIYomNxhUBdlhifnZ1SWbxpzun//V/OV/lTDlXfdHZl2kM9HiEbTZYX0cfiyk4ZjmZnnuTziZk8F1xTypnht2K5lOOWkIJEGiIiNAgi3fOiISXKTWsNck1it280qJQk7jfVkAgioikUrhenREhHCewKiaGacOEEDopdT6BDJvibeAF6YgylF0kUKYUnSC@UqErcrpy4CG3ffDMeDt25sYzuDeXhse1fy@qT2XqwkOVwJQBVa3B5a0x3sQHUv11d2XfIwDFzWQPl23@2vVhkETmyqfUQdeUwYDAT2d03A@25Ds/tiU3YDuj@IjfRmoL2o6poAPdD6CrHxYsCmAsOLZiX1gdYXP144wUecePb8Q8)

The function must take input as a decimal string.
This is because the `f(0)` attempts to coerce `'0b'` to number, which results in `NaN`, but `f('0')` uses `'0b0'`.

Ungolfed and explained

```javascript
n => `0b${      // create a string template literal starting for a binary number
  (g = n =>     // define a function g that creates a reversed binary string
    n ?         // if n is not zero
      n % 2 +   // put least sig. bit to the front
      g(n >> 1) // recursively add the rest
    :           // if n is 0
      ''        // return empty string
  )(n)          // call g with n
}` ** 2         // exponent operation implicitly coerces string to number
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ḃrḂ²
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#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)

##### Explanation

```python
ḃrḂ²  # Implicit input
ḃ     # To binary
 r    # Reverse
  Ḃ   # From binary
   ²  # Square
      # Implicit output
```